# keycloak file import using admin CLI

Tags: keycloak

I am working on keycloak 4.1.0 using CLI(kcadm).

According to the documentation 
`bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import` is the command used to import which tells

> syntax not found

Is there any other way this could be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can check keycloak documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_export_import) for importing and exporting. 
Import file should be in json format.

```
bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile -Dkeycloak.migration.file=import_data.json -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING
```